# How to get r coefficients separately for every cross validation fold in glmnet model

Tags: r, loops, cross-validation, glmnet

For doing the 5K cross validation, I want to prepare training and testing sets to apply to `cv.glmnet` function. There is a nested list of 2 elements that each has 5 elements, training.x and testing.x respectively. Here is the minimal example of the list structure:

```
list_x <- list(list(list(ENSG0000014 = structure(list(`1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", 
"1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", "0", "0"), `1_43223126_C_T_b37` = c("0", 
"1", "0"), `1_43223317_T_C_b37` = c("1", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), ENSG0000015 = structure(list(
    `1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", "1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", 
    "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))), list(ENSG0000014 = structure(list(`1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", 
"1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", "0", "0"), `1_43223126_C_T_b37` = c("0", 
"1", "0"), `1_43223317_T_C_b37` = c("1", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), ENSG0000015 = structure(list(
    `1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", "1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", 
    "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))), list(ENSG0000014 = structure(list(`1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", 
"1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", "0", "0"), `1_43223126_C_T_b37` = c("0", 
"1", "0"), `1_43223317_T_C_b37` = c("1", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), ENSG0000015 = structure(list(
    `1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", "1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", 
    "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))), list(ENSG0000014 = structure(list(`1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", 
"1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", "0", "0"), `1_43223126_C_T_b37` = c("0", 
"1", "0"), `1_43223317_T_C_b37` = c("1", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), ENSG0000015 = structure(list(
    `1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", "1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", 
    "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))), list(ENSG0000014 = structure(list(`1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", 
"1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", "0", "0"), `1_43223126_C_T_b37` = c("0", 
"1", "0"), `1_43223317_T_C_b37` = c("1", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), ENSG0000015 = structure(list(
    `1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", "1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", 
    "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")))), list(list(ENSG0000014 = structure(list(`1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", 
"1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", "0", "0"), `1_43223126_C_T_b37` = c("0", 
"1", "0"), `1_43223317_T_C_b37` = c("1", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), ENSG0000015 = structure(list(
    `1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", "1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", 
    "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))), list(ENSG0000014 = structure(list(`1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", 
"1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", "0", "0"), `1_43223126_C_T_b37` = c("0", 
"1", "0"), `1_43223317_T_C_b37` = c("1", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), ENSG0000015 = structure(list(
    `1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", "1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", 
    "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))), list(ENSG0000014 = structure(list(`1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", 
"1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", "0", "0"), `1_43223126_C_T_b37` = c("0", 
"1", "0"), `1_43223317_T_C_b37` = c("1", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), ENSG0000015 = structure(list(
    `1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", "1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", 
    "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))), list(ENSG0000014 = structure(list(`1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", 
"1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", "0", "0"), `1_43223126_C_T_b37` = c("0", 
"1", "0"), `1_43223317_T_C_b37` = c("1", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), ENSG0000015 = structure(list(
    `1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", "1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", 
    "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))), list(ENSG0000014 = structure(list(`1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", 
"1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", "0", "0"), `1_43223126_C_T_b37` = c("0", 
"1", "0"), `1_43223317_T_C_b37` = c("1", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), ENSG0000015 = structure(list(
    `1_43222779_A_G_b37` = c("1", "1", "2"), `1_43222856_A_G_b37` = c("0", 
    "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")))))
```

And here is the structure of training.y data:

```
list_y <- list(list(ENSG0000014 = structure(list(expr = c(" 9.940670e-02", 
" 1.289670e-01", "-7.394904e-03")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), ENSG0000015 = structure(list(expr = c(" 9.940670e-02", 
" 1.289670e-01", "-7.394904e-03")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))), list(ENSG0000014 = structure(list(expr = c(" 9.940670e-02", 
" 1.289670e-01", "-7.394904e-03")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), ENSG0000015 = structure(list(expr = c(" 9.940670e-02", 
" 1.289670e-01", "-7.394904e-03")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))), list(ENSG0000014 = structure(list(expr = c(" 9.940670e-02", 
" 1.289670e-01", "-7.394904e-03")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), ENSG0000015 = structure(list(expr = c(" 9.940670e-02", 
" 1.289670e-01", "-7.394904e-03")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))), list(ENSG0000014 = structure(list(expr = c(" 9.940670e-02", 
" 1.289670e-01", "-7.394904e-03")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), ENSG0000015 = structure(list(expr = c(" 9.940670e-02", 
" 1.289670e-01", "-7.394904e-03")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))), list(ENSG0000014 = structure(list(expr = c(" 9.940670e-02", 
" 1.289670e-01", "-7.394904e-03")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), ENSG0000015 = structure(list(expr = c(" 9.940670e-02", 
" 1.289670e-01", "-7.394904e-03")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))))
```

It is known that `cv.glmnet` does not accept formula notation, so x and y must be passed in separately and also requested input is a matrix, not a dataframe. Based on these two things, I need to prepare the training and testing data in a loop to get each gene in every fold. Then, after getting the best lambda (lambda.1se) from cv.glmnet, fitting the ridge regression model (alpha = 0) through `glmnet` function in a way to get the predicted model, 5 r coefficient for each gene separately, and then average of all.

I'd appreciate if you can help.

Comment: `cv.glmnet` does the CV internally, so there is no need to split the data manually in different resamples or folds. Just have one matrix for the features `x` and one vector of responses `y`. There is also the `tidymodels` packages, so you do not have to reinvent the data structure.

Comment: @danlooo But does `cv.glmnet` do a nested cross-validation?

Comment: What is your nesting exactly? Different parameters e.g. lambda is one nesting, whats the other?

Comment: I need to have the coefficient analysis data for each fold separately. Also, I can't get all genes data in one matrix since the number of columns in every gene vary from each other. So should be prepared in a structure like a loop so that glmnet can get the data for each gene in every fold at the time .

Comment: Do you just wana build two independent models, one for gene 14 and the other for gene 15? Or do you need one model predicting both outcomes using the same set of parameter weights?

Comment: I actually want to get the CV result and then prediction for each fold. But all the genes would be analysed together. At the end, there would be 5 r coefficients and I will get the average of those five. But I want to have access to the coeffiecients of each fold too. Of course the real data has manay more genes in each fold.

Comment: Usually you have one outcome (gene expression), so you just have one nesting to tune the parameters. Here is a tutorial about CV in R: https://www.tidymodels.org/start/resampling/  Then you just rerun the same code with all the other genes to be predicted. If you really want to have one model predicting multiple genes at the same time, take a look at https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/models/pls/